# How to examine the potential filesize/bitmap size before decoding the bitmap from file path in android?

Tags: android, bitmap

After using the device camera I get a 52MB bitmap and I decode it this way:

```
    try {
        bitmapLarge = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, bitmapOptions);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        try {
            bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = 2;
            bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bitmapLarge = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, bitmapOptions);
            bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError ex2) {
            ex2.printStackTrace();
            try {
                bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = 4;
                bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                bitmapLarge = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, bitmapOptions);
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError ex3) {
                ex3.printStackTrace();
                bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = 8;
                bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                bitmapLarge = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, bitmapOptions);
                bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
            }
            bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("resizing bitmap", "#### NULL");
        bitmapLarge = null;
        return null;
    }
```

I get a huge OutOfMemoryError at the first attempt to decodeFile:

```
12-15 18:24:24.393: E/dalvikvm-heap(12890): Out of memory on a 51916816-byte allocation.
```

How do I know what the size of the bitmap would be BEFORE trying to do anything with it?

And even if this is possible, how do I decode it downsampled somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing `bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;` change that to `true` and you will get back the bounds of the image

you should probably read this too http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 2):

with `inJustDecodeBounds = true`. You will get back a null `bitmap`, but the `bitmapOptions` object will be filled with Bitmap's width and height. Then it is just Mathematic.. You need `width * height * 4` bytes to keep your bitmap in memory

Comment: What's the magic "4" here, and is it always going to be 4?  I sense there needs to be a pixel type test here.

Comment: 4 channels. Argb